python selenium cant click on button on reddit
i just cant click the button to open image on site https://www.reddit.com/r/NFT/submit/?type=IMAGE with python selenium
can someone write a code on selenium which can click on this buttton, enter photo path, which saved in a variable and press enter to download the image

what did you try? where is your code? where are you stuck in your code?  Please read this

i did
upload_button = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'device-upload-button').shadow_root
and
upload_button = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'device-upload-button')
and all other types of find element by
